# passenger: undefined symbol rb_intern2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, passenger

I installed Passanger mod over the Apache webserver and tried to run my application (one uses `Rails 3.2.8` and `Ruby 1.9.3-p194`).

Firstly i encountered an error like "*`bundler` gem could not be found*". Searching a bit i found a solution - i just needed to add the `GEM_PATH` environment variable to my virtual host.

But then i faced another issue: almost each gem throws an exception like this (*Apache error log*):

```
Rack: /home/shybovycha/projects/rails/blog: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/ext/parser.so: undefined symbol: rb_intern2
*** Exception EOFError in spawn manager (Unexpected end-of-file detected.) (process 31821):
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:306:in `unmarshal_and_raise_errors'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:71:in `spawn_application'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:41:in `spawn_application'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:159:in `spawn_application'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:287:in `handle_spawn_application'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
        from /usr/lib/phusion_passenger/passenger-spawn-server:61
[ pid=31752 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:727 time=2012-08-31 12:51:47.973 ]:
  Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application '/home/shybovycha/projects/rails/blog': The spawn server has exited unexpectedly.
  Backtrace:
     (empty)
```

Trying reinstalling gems, with and without `--platform` option gave me nothing.

**Note:** `rails server` proceeds perfectly.

Help me to deal with this, please!

Comment: how did you work around this problem?

Comment: @hhamilton `sudo bundle update` ??? I did not remember, actually...